# DTLS AES 256 CBC with SHA, how do I calculate the final encrypted handshake message

Tags: dtls, tls1.1

I'm trying to understand how the final Encrypted Handshake message works

To do this, I'm trying to ensure that my algorithm gives the same result as this example that works:

https://www.cloudshark.org/captures/56acf0481a79

I'm quiet sure that DTLS 1.0 is following RFC 4347 due to the 0xFEFF header.

The known are

```
Preshared Key: 123456789012345678901234567890aa
Server Random: d87eeeb79b8c5bb29a6e01236ca75a00d515ac18a060e7b4dd4aa85d66130b41
Client Random: df14cead6b8a82a7f0fa710ed4437fa747f5f20e160b6865a3486ca3abc1c427
Cipher Suite: TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
```

I'm doing the following step:

Pre Master Secret

> The premaster secret is formed as follows: if the PSK is N octets long, concatenate a uint16 with the value N, N zero octets, a second uint16 with the value N, and the PSK itself. ([RFC 4279 Section 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4279#section-2))

```
  001000000000000000000000000000000000
  0010123456789012345678901234567890aa
```

The master_secret = PRF(pre_master_secret, "master secret", ClientHello.random + ServerHello.random)
[0..47];

> The PRF is defined as combining two different hashing functions. [Section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246#section-5) of RFC 2246:

```
197c358a9de99d7c50120aea40af2095
c7c340719385f23f5355004c07d9f896
681942c494eb0d77992c3acf1bc92e4f
```

The key_block = PRF(SecurityParameters.master_secret, "key expansion", ServerHello.random + ClientHello.Random) according to RFC4346 [Section 6.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#section-6.3)

- 20 bytes for a client MAC key (SHA1)
- 20 bytes for a server MAC key (SHA1)
- 32 bytes for a client encryption key (AES256)
- 32 bytes for a server encryption key (AES256)
- 16 bytes for a client IV (AES uses 128-bit blocks)
- 16 bytes for a server IV (AES uses 128-bit blocks)

In this case we need to generate 136 byte

```
4921654a071c95e2ddb8e3a8162258fa
acffdd8def0a0b7ce49f492a6f088af9
e539aae851232337c90564d6d4b01fb1
0b34466fe379e34b10b5738203453253
3fe0823297ca5c111b3d23dfb6145447
a638a84376f21a845de503b324f2beab
e145274f680519cc2ecc088e0bf6fb37
69b31c82df3ce706f6ac2cb45226234a
dbd564a2b43c79ee
```

If the above is correct then

```
Client Write Key: c90564d6d4b01fb10b34466fe379e34b
                  10b57382034532533fe0823297ca5c11
Client Write IV: 2ecc088e0bf6fb3769b31c82df3ce706
```

Therefore, if I decrypt the client handshake encrypted record with the key and IV above I get

```
7fd6314cf559a60c14a44a2fd4ac5494
1400000c000200000000000ce93fd3d8
557a3eb9574d25943e01f797b982a5ed
35ce268520ef7475144441ea03030303
```

How do I get the value above?

I understand that this needs to be hashed (the concatenation of Client Hello + Sever Hello + Sever Hello Done + Client Key Exchange)

```
010000390000000000000039feffdf14
cead6b8a82a7f0fa710ed4437fa747f5
f20e160b6865a3486ca3abc1c4270000
0006008d008c00ff0100000900230000
000f0001010200003600000000000000
36feffd87eeeb79b8c5bb29a6e01236c
a75a00d515ac18a060e7b4dd4aa85d66
130b4100008d00000eff010001000023
0000000f0001010e0000000001000000
00000010000011000100000000001100
0f436c69656e745f6964656e74697479
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first row of the encrypted finished data is IV. Therefore, in your decrypted output you need to remove the first 16 bytes, which gives us:

```
14 00 00 0C 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 0C E9 3F D3 D8
55 7A 3E B9 57 4D 25 94 3E 01 F7 97 B9 82 A5 ED
35 CE 26 85 20 EF 74 75 14 44 41 EA 03 03 03 03
```

Starting from the end we have the following sections:

#### PADDING (4 bytes)

The last four bytes (`03 03 03 03`) are padding so we may skip them.

#### MAC (20 bytes)

The next 20 bytes (`3e 01 f7 97 b9 82 a5 ed 35 ce 26 85 20 ef 74 75 14 44 41 ea`) are HMAC-SHA1 calculated in a peculiar way: you need to first append epoch + message sequence number (in our case `00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00`), then add TLS record header (without the epoch and sequence number) with the content size set to the actual content size (`0x18` in our case):

```
00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 16 FE FF 00 18 14 00 00
0C 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 0C E9 3F D3 D8 55 7A 3E
B9 57 4D 25 94
```

Let's save it to a file named `handshake-client-finished-without-mac.bin` and call openssl:

```
$ openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac $(cat client-mac-key.bin) handshake-client-finished-without-mac.bin
HMAC-SHA1(handshake-client-finished-without-mac.bin)= 3e01f797b982a5ed35ce268520ef7475144441ea
```

The client MAC key (from the key block that you already generated) is:

```
49 21 65 4A 07 1C 95 E2 DD B8 E3 A8 16 22 58 FA
AC FF DD 8D
```

We just verified that the MAC is correct. Let's move forward with the message bytes.

#### VERIFY DATA (12 bytes)

Next 12 bytes (`E9 3F D3 D8 55 7A 3E B9 57 4D 25 94`) is the Verify Data. You correctly extracted the bytes from all the previous messages. We need now to calculate MD5 and SHA1 hash of those bytes:

```
$ openssl dgst -md5 to_hash.bin
MD5(to_hash.bin)= fcc3d19566dc07777834ebddf9dd5dc4

$ openssl dgst -sha1 to_hash.bin
SHA1(to_hash.bin)= 2b069b971ceb63e2f0e6d2687479a10b0aee6abd
```

Then combine them (md5+sha1) and save them to `client-data-for-prf.bin`. Finally, we calculate the 12 bytes using the PRF function (I used my PRF implementation from [github](https://github.com/lowleveldesign/diagnostics-tools/tree/master/PRF)):

```
.\PRF.exe -l "client finished" -s .\master-secret.bin -d .\client-data-for-prf.bin -o
 client-prf-result.bin -n 12
```

The `client-prf-result.bin` will contain bytes equal to the verify data from the encrypted message.

#### HANDSHAKE HEADER (12 bytes)

```
Offset Field
00     Handshake Type: Finished (20)
01     Length: 12
04     Message Sequence: 2
06    Fragment Offset: 0
09    Fragment Length: 12
```

#### *Side note*

If you are ever stuck again when playing with the TLS you may check Wireshark debug logs, which reveal a lot about what's happening on the wire. Right click on any of the DTLS frames and open the protocol preferences:

[image: DTLS preferences]

Then set the pre-shared key that you already have and pick a file where you would like to save the logs:

[image: Keys settings]

Click OK and Wireshark should decrypt your TLS data and give you a lot of detailed information in the log file.

Comment: I've been going up and down with that problem. thank you!